# What does it mean by "assignment to" in the gollowing?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I've founded the following part as a definition for "assignment":

> You can refer to someone being given a particular task or job as their
> assignment to the task or job.

Now my question is: what does it mean by "assignment to Greece" came in the following:

> The Australian division was scheduled for **assignment to** Greece.

Comment: They were assigned to be sent to Greece to do some task (it would help if you told us more of the context).

Comment: @KateBunting So would you tell me that how you found out that they should be "sent" to Greece? Can you give me some examples too?

Comment: Since you didn't tell us the context (division of what?), I thought that being sent to Greece was the most likely meaning. If not, they were assigned the task of working on something relating to Greece.

Comment: @KateBunting Because I don't have more information to say, I just grabbed this example from "Collins Dictionary" and sadly didn't find anything that refer to a context or something! Thanks at all.

Comment: It always helps to give the source of a quotation - if it's just an example from a dictionary, tell us so!